# Trace radiobutton value defined in child class and pass it to parent class in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, parent-child, trace

I am new to Python and Tkinter so unable to figure out which might be the simplest thing to do. Could someone please check the below code and tell me how can I trace value returned by radiobutton defined in child class and pass it to parent class. I get following error after compiling:

`AttributeError: Toplevel instance has no attribute 'trace_fun'`

I am not sure why am I getting this error since I have defined `trace_fun` in child class body. I have successfully traced variables in parent class but getting above error while trying to do it in the child class.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Parent(Frame):
    classvar = 0

    def __init__(self):

        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Parent WIndow")
        self.master.geometry("200x100")
        self.grid()

        self._button = Button(self, text="Create", width=10, command=self.new_window)
        self._button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W)

    def new_window(self):
        self.new = Child()

class Child(Parent, Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        Parent.__init__(self)
        new = Frame.__init__(self)
        new = Toplevel(self)
        new.title("Child Window")
        new.grid()

        new._var = IntVar()
        new._var.set(0)
        new._var.trace("w", new.trace_fun)

        new._radioButton = Radiobutton(new, text = "Option 1", variable = new._var, value = 1)
        new._radioButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

        new._radioButton2 = Radiobutton(new, text = "Option 2", variable = new._var, value = 2)
        new._radioButton2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

        new._button = Button(new, text = 'Ok', command=new.destroy)
        new._button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

    def trace_fun(new, *args):

        print new._var.get()
        Parent.classvar = new._var.get()


obj = Parent()

def main():
    obj.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You've overwritten your `new` variable here:

```
   new = Frame.__init__(self)
   new = Toplevel(self)
```

After those two statements execute, `new` is equal to an instance of the Toplevel class.

Next, this code executes:

```
new._var.trace("w", new.trace_fun)
```

and in particular:

```
new.trace_fun
```

So, you have a Toplevel instance trying to access an attribute named trace_fun.  The error message is telling you that the Toplevel class does not have any attribute named trace_fun.

Edit:

You can't call trace_fun on a Toplevel instance--ever.  Nor can you call trace_fun on a Parent instance--ever.  So print out a copy of your program, then get a pen and circle all the variables that are Toplevel instances; then circle all the variables that are Parent instances.  You can't call trace_fun on any of those variables.  Alternatively, circle all the variables that are Child instances.  You *can* call trace_fun on those variables.

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
class Child:
    def do_stuff(self):     #1) self is an instance of class Child, i.e. the object that is calling this method
        self.trace_fun()    #2) The Child class defines a method named trace_fun()
                            #3) Therefore, self can call trace_fun()
        x = self.trace_fun  #4) ...or you can assign self.trace_fun to a variable
                            #5) ...or pass self.trace_fun to another function

    def trace_fun(self):
        print 'hello'

d = Chile()
d.do_stuff()

--output:--
hello
```

It doesn't look like you have a Parent/Child relationship between your two frames--because the Child frame doesn't use anything inherited from the Parent frame.  So you could just create two separate frames for your app.  Here is an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class EntryFrame(tk.Frame):
    classvar = 0

    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root) #Send root as the parent arg to Frame's __init__ method
        root.title("Parent Window")
        root.geometry("400x200")

        tk.Label(self, text="First").grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Second").grid(row=1)

        e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        e2 = tk.Entry(self)

        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Create", width=10, command=self.create_new_window)
        button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)

        self.grid()

    def create_new_window(self):
        RadioButtonFrame()


class RadioButtonFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        new_top_level = tk.Toplevel()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, new_top_level) #Send new_top_level as the parent arg to Frame's __init__ method

        new_top_level.title("Radio Button Window")
        new_top_level.geometry('400x300+0+300') # "width x height + x + y"

        self.int_var = int_var = tk.IntVar()
        int_var.trace("w", self.trace_func)
        int_var.set(0)

        rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Option 1", variable = int_var, value = 1)
        rb1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=10, pady=10)

        rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Option 2", variable = int_var, value = 2)
        rb2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=10, pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Ok', command=new_top_level.destroy)
        button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

        self.grid()

    def trace_func(self, *args):
        radio_val = self.int_var.get()
        print radio_val

        EntryFrame.classvar = radio_val


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_frame = EntryFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I changed Toplevel instance variable name from new to new2 and tried to call trace_fun from new2 but still I am getting the same error i.e. Toplevel instance has no attribute trace_fun. I hope I understood you correctly what you suggested me to do.

Comment: @ 7stud., Thank you for detailed explanation. It was helpful in understanding some of the concepts related to interaction of two frames.

Answer (score -1):

By making slight changes, now my code is working perfectly. Posting new code for someone stuck on the same point as me earlier. Changes can be seen in the below code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Parent:
    classvar = 0

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.title("Parent Window")
        self.master.geometry("400x100")
        self.frame.grid()

        self._button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Create", width=10, command=self.new_window)
        self._button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

    def new_window(self):
        self.child_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Child(self.child_window)

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.title("Child Window")
        self.frame.grid()

        self._var = IntVar()
        self._var.set(0)
        self._var.trace("w", self.trace_fun)

        self._radioButton = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text = "Option 1", variable = self._var, value = 1)
        self._radioButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

        self._radioButton2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text = "Option 2", variable = self._var, value = 2)
        self._radioButton2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

        self._button = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Ok', command=self.master.destroy)
        self._button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

    def trace_fun(self, *args):
        Parent.classvar = self._var.get()
        print Parent.classvar


root = tk.Tk()
obj = Parent(root)

def main():
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained the critical differences. What did you change? Without explaining, a reader is forced to compare the code line-by-line looking for differences.